# Cannot docker build because of "Couldn't run auplink before unmount" error

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I run `docker build` I get this:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  10.24kB
WARN[11935] Couldn't run auplink before unmount /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/21647778a50f097d4535246ec5206960dd909f4bb8b0e3d04fdd53a7402fc2de-init: exec: "auplink": executable file not found in $PATH 
Step 1/2 : FROM debian:jessie
 ---> 86baf4e8cde9
Step 2/2 : RUN apt-get update
WARN[11935] Couldn't run auplink before unmount /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/21647778a50f097d4535246ec5206960dd909f4bb8b0e3d04fdd53a7402fc2de: exec: "auplink": executable file not found in $PATH 
 ---> Running in 1fef9bef5bf7
ERRO[11934] containerd: start container                   error="shim error: fork/exec /usr/bin/docker-runc: exec format error" id=1fef9bef5bf77141a97669d2aa785e74f9027a849919a937f714e93fbae3916d
ERRO[11935] Create container failed with error: shim error: fork/exec /usr/bin/docker-runc: exec format error 
ERRO[11934] containerd: deleting container                error="fork/exec /usr/bin/docker-runc: exec format error: \"\""
WARN[11935] Couldn't run auplink before unmount /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/21647778a50f097d4535246ec5206960dd909f4bb8b0e3d04fdd53a7402fc2de: exec: "auplink": executable file not found in $PATH 
shim error: fork/exec /usr/bin/docker-runc: exec format error
```

Here is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update
```

What is the issue? It makes no sens to me.

```
ll /usr/bin | grep docker
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    18471276 Aug  3 22:08 docker*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     9938352 Aug  3 22:08 docker-containerd*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     8941944 Aug  3 22:08 docker-containerd-ctr*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     3824920 Aug  3 22:08 docker-containerd-shim*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    40328816 Aug  3 22:08 dockerd*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root           0 Aug  3 22:08 docker-init*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root           0 Aug  3 22:08 docker-proxy*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root           0 Aug  3 22:08 docker-runc*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     8962864 Aug  3 21:40 docker-volume-local-persist*
```

Installing from https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/binaries/

`file $(which docker-runc)`:

```
/usr/bin/docker-runc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=e3d80e183baf26a9d48c3f0435931d42aa1bf340, not stripped
```

lsb_release -a

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

docker --version

```
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
```

dockerd --version

```
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
```

docker-containerd --version

```
containerd version 0.2.3 commit: cfb82a876ecc11b5ca0977d1733adbe58599088a
```

docker-containerd-ctr --version

```
ctr version 0.2.3 commit: cfb82a876ecc11b5ca0977d1733adbe58599088a
```

docker-init --version

```
tini version 0.13.0 - git.949e6fa
```

docker-runc --version

```
runc version 1.0.0-rc3
commit: 2d41c047c83e09a6d61d464906feb2a2f3c52aa4
spec: 1.0.0-rc5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this running on a non-Intel/ARM 64-bit Ubuntu? For example a Raspberry Pi or ARM64 CPU? This error:

`shim error: fork/exec /usr/bin/docker-runc: exec format error`

Would imply that either (a) the binary install on your machine is corrupted in some way, or (b) you are attempting to run a binary for a different architecture on your system.

Can you post the output of `uname -a` and `file /usr/bin/docker-runc`? That might help narrow down the source of your problem.

Comment: uname -a `Linux badger 4.10.0-30-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 31 19:38:17 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: No output for `docker-runc`

Comment: I updated my question. For some reason `docker-runc` was empty. Anyways, now is not empty anymore.

Comment: It's disconcerting that you had zero length files on your filesystem; any chance you had an out of disk space condition? Makes me wonder if the layers of the `debian:jessie` image were impacted as well, giving you the exec format errors (e.g. missing/corrupted binary content). Can you try a different image and pull and run it first to verify? E.g. `docker pull alpine:latest` and `docker run -ti --rm alpine:latest sh`?

Comment: It's weird because I still have a lot of disk space: `/dev/sda1        19G  4.7G   15G  25% /` I will try out what you are proposing.

Comment: **any chance you had an out of disk space condition?** No idea. Is there a log file I can check?

Comment: `docker pull alpine:latest`: `latest: Pulling from library/alpine
Digest: sha256:1072e499f3f655a032e88542330cf75b02e7bdf673278f701d7ba61629ee3ebe
Status: Image is up to date for alpine:latest`

Comment: Right now when I start `dockerd &` I get multiple warnings: `WARN[0000] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period`, `WARN[0000] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime`, `WARN[0000] libcontainerd: client is out of sync, restore was called on a fully synced container`, `WARN[0000] libcontainerd: failed to retrieve container`, `WARN[0000] failed to cleanup ipc mounts:`, `failed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/28c274e176c9c112f8bc73f6916860665c63f1407ca2670944deee7b6ae2e747/shm: invalid argument`. Anyways the others are similar. I don't know if it helps.

Comment: Maybe this is related: https://serverfault.com/questions/867996/apt-get-install-linux-image-extra-getting-w-mdadm-etc-mdadm-mdadm-conf-defin

Comment: Also I am running the host on a VM VirtualBox/Vagrant.

Comment: Given you had some weird issues about zero-length files in your Docker installation, and there seems to be some leftover cruft in `/var/lib/docker`; assuming this is a test VM without any critical work, would you be open to stopping the daemon, `rm -fR /var/lib/docker` and then starting the daemon again? Given a fresh pull of an image worked and runs, I don't see any problem with the engine itself or `docker-runc` anymore.

Comment: `WARN[0001] failed to rename /var/lib/docker/tmp for background deletion: rename /var/lib/docker/tmp /var/lib/docker/tmp-old: no such file or directory. Deleting synchronously` got this new warning. Maybe it's normal.

Comment: Seems to work when I run `docker run hello-world`. But I am still getting these warnings: `WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period` and `WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime`.

Comment: Another detail: I try installing it with apt-get. So it might be different than the previous binary setup. Let me see tomorrow. By the way thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something related to aufs FS, What OS Do you use ? and Did you recently updated your machine ?

**Update:**

For `CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP_ENABLED: missing, CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED: missing and warning: /proc/config.gz does not exist, searching other paths for kernel config ...`

These are missing kernel configuration and flags, Please make sure you installed `linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)` `linux-image-extra-virtual`, First make sure you stopped docker daemon `sudo systemctl stop docker` and install these packages (contains extra driver that support containers and aufs check docker docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu):

`sudo apt-get install \
    linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) \
    linux-image-extra-virtual`

And update your grub `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` add these`cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1` to your `/etc/default/grub`configuration file then update your grub `sudo update-grub` check https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4250 && https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/4251

For `aufs` problems there is another solution for modern dockers as docker moved from `aufs` to `overlay` and `overlay2` is to configure your machine and apply `overlay` but make sure you backed up your docker images and containers as this fix might make you lose them check [Unable to start Docker Service in Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227349/unable-to-start-docker-service-in-ubuntu-16-04/37640824)

Comment: I forgot to added sorry. I just added it. You are right. I installed `cgroup-lite` and `aufs-tools`. But I am still getting some of the other errors.

Comment: I did also tried running this script:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moby/moby/master/contrib/check-config.sh to help track down what the issue or issues are. I get this: `CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP_ENABLED: missing`, `CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED: missing` and `warning: /proc/config.gz does not exist, searching other paths for kernel config ...`

Comment: `CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP_ENABLED: missing` -- `(cgroup swap accounting is currently enabled)
` and `CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED: missing`

Comment: I am unsure I need to add linux-image-extra (https://askubuntu.com/questions/153023/what-is-the-linux-image-extra-package-for-and-do-i-need-it). I tried it to no result.

Comment: Yes it's not necessary but as I mentioned it contains extra drivers, Anyway Which docker version do you have? and Did you install it from the package manager or manually?

Comment: `dockerd --version`: `Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87`

Comment: From a package manager or manually ? and what's the output of `file $(which docker-runc)`

Comment: I am installing from https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/binaries/

Comment: `file $(which docker-runc)`: `/usr/bin/docker-runc: empty`

Comment: I just notice that docker-runc is empty... Very strange. I will re-download it...

Comment: `file $(which docker-runc)` : `/usr/bin/docker-runc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=e3d80e183baf26a9d48c3f0435931d42aa1bf340, not stripped`

Comment: It's risky to install from source and not necessary specially when you have the package distributed to your package manager that will dynamically link binaries, manage versions and dependencies. Did you mount your cgroupfs, or Did you apt-get install  `aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount libltdl7` these are the dependencies for the official docker-ce installation.

Comment: Not from the source but from the binary. It was already compiled. I installed `cgroup-lite` not `cgroupfs-mount` and not `libltdl7`. I did install `aufs-tools`.

Comment: Alright kindly make sure you have them. mounting cgroups is important for docker.

Comment: Only `cgroupfs-mount` is not installed.

Comment: I was able to start some of my containers. But I am getting (I don't know if this is related) `failed to cleanup ipc mounts:`, `failed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/b8335587ad37a36a35fc2f1eb57b3b3d91f61af75262eb075b9045664885ee30/shm: invalid argument`, `libcontainerd: client is out of sync, restore was called on a fully synced container (28c274e176c9c112f8bc73f6916860665c63f1407ca2670944deee7b6ae2e747).`, `libcontainerd: failed to retrieve container 28c274e176c9c112f8bc73f6916860665c63f1407ca2670944deee7b6ae2e747 state: rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: container not found`

Comment: It might relate to: `Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period`, `Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime`