# Unit docker.service is not loaded properly observed while execute service docker start on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I just successfully installed docker on ubuntu machine but I'm not able to start and it throws below error message

**Command:**

> sudo service docker start

**Error:**

```
Job for docker.socket failed. See "systemctl status docker.socket" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status docker.service' for details
```

.

System details:

> Uname -a
>
> Linux instance-1 4.15.0-1029-gcp #31~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 22
>   13:06:42 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962

Also I do see the below while check the docker info:

```
sudo docker info
[sudo] password for achu:
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I got below details if I run systemctl status docker.socket

```
● docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: service-start-limit-hit) since Thu 2019-05-09 03:53:13 PDT; 5h 0min ago
   Listen: /var/run/docker.sock (Stream
```

Also I just checked docker.socket file and I don't see any docker.sock in /var/run/docker.sock location.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "See "systemctl status docker.socket" and "journalctl -xe" for details." - did you check for something suspicious there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227349/unable-to-start-docker-service-in-ubuntu-16-04